# Create a post controller spec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, controller

I am doing a controller test but it seems that spec.rb is wrong.
Do you have a suggestion ?

This is my `posts_controller.rb`:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

 def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @wall
    end
 end

 def destroy
    @post.destroy
  end 
  private
   def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:wall, :content)
   end
 end
```

and this is my `posts_controller_spec.rb`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe PostsController do
  let(:wall) { create(:wall) }

  describe "#create" do
      it "saves the new post in the wall" do
      post :create, { wall_id: wall, content: "Some text I would like to put in my post" } 
      end
  end

  describe "#destroy" do
    it "deletes the post in the wall" do
    end
  end
end
```

could you please help me to correct my spec.rb?
this is my error:

PostsController
  #create
    saves the new post in the wall (FAILED - 1)
  #destroy
    deletes the post in the wall

Failures:

1) PostsController#create saves the new post in the wall
     Failure/Error: post :create, post: { wall: wall, content: "Some text I would like to put in my post" }
     ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
       Wall(#2159949860) expected, got String(#2155957040)
     # ./app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:3:in `create'
     # ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:8:in`block (3 levels) in '
     # -e:1:in `'

Finished in 0.9743 seconds (files took 3.94 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/posts_controller_spec.rb:7 # PostsController#create saves the new post in the wall

Thank you in advance

Comment: what is your RSpec version?

Comment: What error do you have?

Comment: hello, my version is ruby-2.1.1/gems/rspec-core-3.0.2 .

Answer (score 1):

Your spec doesn't include any expectations, so it's "wrong" in that sense. I suggest you google "RSpec expectations" and/or read the docs (i.e. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs).

As for the error you mentioned in your comment, that reflects a problem with your production code (i.e. the lack of a `redirect` or `render` or some `create` template in the case the `@post.save` returns nil). Again, googling the error should yield information to help you address this problem or your can read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html. If you're new to Rails entirely, I suggest following one of the tutorials, such as https://www.railstutorial.org/

You should also update your question to include that error information, since it's highly relevant and the question is essentially incomplete without it.

Comment: You wrote your error in the comment. It should be in the question itself. In any event, my answer indicated why you were getting that error.

Comment: Peter thanks for your help, but could you give more specific examples or links that may help me? Thank you.

Comment: I added some documentation references, but please update your question to include the error information.  Readers should not have to consult the comments to get critical information.

Answer (score 0):

You should expect something on your tests. For example, you could do like this:

```
RSpec.describe PostsController, type: :controller do
  let!(:wall) { create(:wall) } 
  let(:test_post) {
      create(:post, wall_id: wall.id, content: "Something") }
  }

  describe "POST #create" do
    let(:post) { assigns(:post) }
    let(:test_wall) { create(:wall) }

    context "when valid" do
      before(:each) do
        post :create, params: {
          post: attributes_for(:post, wall_id: test_wall.id, content: "Anything")
        }
      end

      it "should save the post" do
        expect(post).to be_persisted
      end

    end
  end
end
```

This way you are expecting a response from rails when you post you parameters. I just coded the post part of the test.